# Official way to scroll to bottom (including footer) in listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I need to programmatically show the end of whole listview including footer.

```
// works only sometimes, sometimes not
// really strange, but as it is, unoficiall way to do this.
listview.setSelection(listview.getCount()-1);
```

Is there any official way from Android developers so we can immidiatelly scroll/go to bottom edge of listview content?

This is basic thing so should be something in docs, but I can't find.. Docs and stackoverflow says nothing, lets change it.

Thanks for help.

Other thing is about why it works only sometimes? (setSelection way)

If I put child to listview that contains "1: some text" and then setVisibility to VISIBLE of footer-child and then scroll to bottom then it works, but if last listview-child contains "2: some text" instead of "1: some text" it doesn't works.. really really strange.

EDIT2:

Find out when setSelection way not work. When you type anything by keyboard into editview, then after it when you try scroll to bottom by setSelection, it will ignore job, or at least ignore footer (so almost bottom reached then)

Answer (score 0):

setSelection() is for select the row, the same as clicking on it.

Just use

```
smoothScrollToPosition(int position)
```

like:

```
listview.smoothScrollToPosition(listview.getMaxScrollAmount());
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Can't find out whatever it works or not, because it doesn't scroll to total end, only scrolls to last child, I need to scroll to the very end including footer.

Comment: Im sorry i didnt read that footer part, ive updated my answer

Comment: try using a high value like 5000, it should scroll to the bottom